# Speed Issue - Font Awesome loading everywhere in Wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome, google-pagespeed, gtmetrix

I use wordpress along with Visual composer. After reviewing speed data in Gtmetrix, I noticed that Font awesome (woff2) is loading everywhere, even on posts unused. I use fontello only in home page.

The Woff2 is loaded by visual composer in this path
/wp-content/cache/min/1/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/bower/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=1665339125

Is there anyway to make this load only on pages/posts where used?

Comment: Is it actually downloading on every page, or is it primarily served from the browser cache? If it's mostly coming from the cache this problem may not be worth your time to fix: cache delivery is fast. Look at the Network tab in your browser devtools.

Answer (score 2):

Well, You can use the asset cleanup plugin to achieve it.

Go to **Plugins > Add New** and search for it by name. Locate **Asset Cleanup** in the search results and click the Install Now button, then click Activate once it’s done installing.

After that, open the page where you don't want to load it, on below you will get unload button beside the script names. Just select it. Done.

Comment: Thanks. Can it be done with a code?

Comment: @pbu Yes, Possible. Detect the pages you want to load the script and push the script to the code. How to detect page type : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83887/return-current-page-type